# AssertEquals for each array stream

Tags: java, junit, stream

I have an array of custom object. I want to loop through each element and check a particular field of that custom object which is of type String. I want to assertEquals that value with an expected value. But I am not able to prepare the statement. Please help.

My code :

```
MyCustomObject[] items = buildItems();
Arrays.asList(items).stream().map(MyCustomObject::getGroupName).forEach(assertEquals("",groupName));
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't collecting anywhere yet. You could do this:

```
List<String> groups = Arrays.asList(items).stream().map(MyCustomObject::getGroupName).collect(Collectors.toList());
groups.forEach(group -> assertEquals(group,groupName));
```

The first line gets the list of strings that are returned with `MyCustomObject::getGroupName` and the second line applies a `Consumer` for each of those strings.

You could also reduce it to a single line, but I think its not always the best to do so because its difficult to read and becomes less interpretable to others :D

Answer (score 0):

That's a bad idea to iterate through the values and check them on each iteration.
For example, what if test failed on 23 iteration of 100 in total (23/100)?
You'll need to re-run the tests again once fix for 23 iteration is done...

Its better to use `parameterized tests`:

- https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests
- https://mkyong.com/junit5/junit-5-parameterized-tests/
- https://www.baeldung.com/parameterized-tests-junit-5

You may have several data provides like other methods or CSV format.